# Was "jih pun"- an origin of "Japan", came from Cantonese?

Tags: vocabulary

Looking up the origin of pun, I came across this for the origin of Japan. I suspect jih pun must be Cantonese. Tang Ho, as resident Cantonese expert, is that so??

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=pun

Japan: 1570s, via Portuguese Japao, Dutch Japan, acquired in Malacca from Malay Japang, from Chinese **jih pun**, literally "sunrise" (equivalent of Japanese Nippon), from jih "sun" + pun "origin." Japan lies to the east of China. Earliest form in Europe was Marco Polo's Chipangu.

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

日 means "Sun"

本 means "origin"

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/410/
>
> 日本 Japan
>
> jat6 bun2   (jyutping)
>
> ri4 ben3, lv4 ben3   (pinyin)

Japanese pronunciation of 日本 is /ni pon/ (Nippon),

Chinese use the Japanese Kanji 日本 and pronounce it as Chinese characters.

- Cantonese pronounce it as /jat6 bun2/
- Mandarin pronounce it as /ri4 ben3/ or / lv4 ben3/

The Cantonese pronunciation of 日本 is in deed more similar to /jih pun/ than the Mandarin pronunciation does.

Comment: Thanks, maybe the transliteration is very old, or from some other South China language. jat bun does come close to jih pun.